# Getting Output of ADSI Command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, output, adsi

I'm trying to delete some local administrator users on multiple computers. Here is the script I used and it works:

```
Import-Csv c:/input.csv | ForEach-Object {
    ([ADSI]"WinNT://$($_.ComputerName)").Invoke("Delete", "user", $_.Username)
}
```

The problem is that I want to get the results of the non-deleted users directly to a text file.
What commands would help me? I've tried `Out-File`, but it's giving me an empty file.

Comment: What do you mean by "results of the non-deleted users"? Do you want to write a list of the remaining local user accounts to a file after the delete operation?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Exactly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Get-WmiObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject) to query a remote host for local users:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv'
$lcl = 'LocalAccount=True'

$csv | ForEach-Object { [ADSI]... }

$csv | Sort-Object -Unique ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
  Get-WmiObject -Computer $_.ComputerName -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter $lcl
} | Select-Object PSComputerName, Name | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```